# How to logon as an admin in a dekstop and turn off user account control settings when i am not in the administrator account?

Tags: windows, uac

Hi um recently my dad thinks that i am downloading too much of things and he set the user account control settings high. This prevents me from even installing bit torrent in my HP touchsmart. I tried several hacking software but it didnt work. My dad is the admin and i am a standard user. So is there any chance that with a standard user account i can turn the uac controls off?

Comment: You know this might best be solved by a father-son discussion.  Hacking around to get the ability to do things you obviously are not intended to do is very bad.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is the entire point of having lower privilege accounts, to prevent you from doing exactly what you are trying to do.

You have two options:

1. Pay for your own Internet connection and PC and do whatever you want (if you where responsible enough to keep a job that paid enough for you to pay for a monthly internet connection I bet your parents would not care how much you downloaded after you got home from work (if you kept your grades up))
2. Follow the rules layed down by the people providing your PC and internet connection.